# Remove lines from a text file

Tags: file, unix, sed, line

I am trying to remove the lines having only 2 words or less than that.
my text file is like this

```
1.just be patient.
2.posters?
3.I have got two jobs, but they're not for you.
4.what?
5.I am.
```

Which should give me output...

```
1.just be patient.
2.I have got two jobs, but they're not for you.
```

Can anyone out there suggest me the best way to do it...
(using `sed` or kind of things)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. your question is NOT clear. Always add 3 simple things in your post, 1st- Sample of Input in CODE TAGS, 2nd- Sample of output in CODE TAGS and 3rd- Add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem. Kindly do the same and let us know then.

Comment: Could you please check my solution once and let me know if that helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be an easy task with `awk` in case you are ok with it.

```
awk 'NF>2' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- Checking condition here `NF>2` if `NF`(number of fields, default variable in `awk`) value is greater than `2`.
- `awk` has by default space as a delimiter so as per OP it should be more than 2 words hence given `>2` condition.
- Now comes part how lines getting printed which are satisfying the condition? `awk` works on method of condition and action, if a condition is TRUE and no action is mentioned(like this code) then by default print of current line will happen.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/\S+/&/3p' file
```

Only print lines with 3 or more groups of non-white spaced characters.